# VideoLan VLC media player showing green texture unity application in different screens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vlc, libvlcsharp

Currently I am working on development of an Interactive standalone application in **Unity 2020.3.30f1**.

Here I am using **VLC player** (https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/vlc-for-unity-windows-133979#description) for streaming external device through **Makito Haivision**.

Application runs on **Dell r7610** Graphic Card : **Nvidia K5000** , it has 6 display screen which are combined through **Mosaic** to create single display.

Unity Sprite, texture, video player works perfect, expect VLC player.
It shows green texture in some screen and works fine in others.
I have attached the issue image.

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ7PR.jpg)

Comment: Could you please open a bug report at https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-unity/?

Comment: Does it happen with any media?

Comment: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-unity/-/issues/151

Answer (score 1):

**Upgrading Mosaic  driver** solved the issue.
But the application becomes slow.